# Clear Shared Preferences on App upgrade

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my

```
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
```

DBHelper function(implementing SQLite open helper) I provide sql queries to modify as per my new version.

But I also want to clear some of my Shared Preferences Details on upgrade.
But Opening sharedPreferences for editing requires Context object, how do I provide it here..?

Comment: DatabaseOpenHelper needs a context in the constructor, so why don't you just save the context as an attribute of yout DatabaseOpenHelper to use it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mContext;

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
            super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // do what ever you want with mContext...
```